# 4.2.2 Android Eclipse Unknown

Tags: android, eclipse

Ever since 4.2.2 - Eclipse shows "unknown" for my device when I pull it in. Here is what I have done:

- Updated Android SDK to newest release (21.1, 16.0.2 - Tools, ADB 1.0.29)
- Attempted to turn the phone on and off again
- Toggle Debug Mode on and off again
- There is only profile on the phone
- Different USB / Ports
- Reboot numerous times.

Any luck here?

UPDATE:

Device ID: 014E1F310600E01D offline

Comment: is your device driver installed properly>

Comment: can u post your mobile model or sure already installed drivers for your mobile?

Comment: I have seen a similar problem with a new device; I searched google for device name and some words from the error message; the solution boiled down to writing the manufacturer's ID (4 hex digits) into some file that has a comment that it should not be changed by hangs.

Comment: How do I know if I have the drivers? The phone is the Samsung Galaxy Nexus - Google's phone unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the PATH was pointing to the old adb (before the update (1.0.29), but once I went to /platform-tools/adb (by running ./adb devices) - everything worked out and now the device is active.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify your device name and model number. i think you didn't install driver for your mobile device. if you already installed it automatically detects your device. To allow app installs from non-Market apps, tap the menu button on your home screen, then choose Settings >> Applications >> Unknown sources.

[image]

Comment: I've already done this. Model is Samsung Galaxy and Model Number is: 014E1F310600E01D

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget about ADB connections that use USB as a means of transport. I've had nothing but problems with it, using several devices from several different manufacturers.  Look in the play store for 'ADB wireless' apps. Those allow you to set up the same connection using WIFI.

At the moment I'm developing an app and have three devices connected to ADB this way. Works like a charm and is much more reliable

Comment: Could you give any examples? This is a pretty openended answer.

Comment: Don't they require being rooted? My device is not rooted.

Comment: Yes they do need to be rooted! sorry about that.  I root all my devices asap for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed USB port and it worked as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart ADB and if there is any notification on the device screen you have to accept it.

## Resolution :

After opening eclipse and before debugging, open the cmd then run " adb kill-server " 
then wait 2-3 seconds then run " adb start-server ", then try to run the program again you will find your device is online.

i hope that helps